# MongoDB Compund Index subdocument query

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema -

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({  
    p_l_d: [perteamdata]   
};
```

Where perteamdata is subdocument. Can I create a compound index on this collection like -

```
{"_id":1,"p_l_d._id":1}
```

?

Comment: I think yes. Is it giving any error? If yes can you please post it.

Comment: No error. Just confirming this.